# spring cloud secret management point to localstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, aws-secrets-manager, localstack

We're using [spring cloud secret management](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.4.4/reference/html/index.html#integrating-your-spring-cloud-application-with-the-aws-secrets-manager) to fetch secrets in AWS and use it our spring application (from property).

For our development set up, we don't want to fetch the value of those properties from actual AWS. Is there a way configure spring cloud secret management so that it points to a different URL? We'll likely point it to our localstack setup.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#endpoint)? In older versions of spring cloud aws, the property name is different and must be set for each service, see [here](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.0/reference/html/index.html#configuring-endpoints)

Comment: @len did you get an answer to this at all?